# Regex, split and Python

Tags: python, regex, split

Can anybody help me to understand what those lines are doing ?

```
VAR_TOKEN_START = '{{'
VAR_TOKEN_END = '}}'
BLOCK_TOKEN_START = '{%'
BLOCK_TOKEN_END = '%}'
TOK_REGEX = re.compile(r"(%s.*?%s|%s.*?%s)" % (
    VAR_TOKEN_START,
    VAR_TOKEN_END,
    BLOCK_TOKEN_START,
    BLOCK_TOKEN_END
))

TOK_REGEX.split('{% each vars %}<i>{{it}}</i>{% endeach %}')
```

I don't understand the `%` on the regex expression. And why we split on `TOK_REGEX` variable expression.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
TOK_REGEX = re.compile(r"(%s.*?%s|%s.*?%s)" % (
    VAR_TOKEN_START,
    VAR_TOKEN_END,
    BLOCK_TOKEN_START,
    BLOCK_TOKEN_END
))
```

uses [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to build a regex in a more understandable manner than just a jumble of characters. The `%` operator replaces each `%s` with the contents of the corresponding string in the following tuple. This allows the author of the code to give meaningful names to the `{{`, `}}`, `{%`, and `%}` parts of the regex.

The [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.split) call:

```
TOK_REGEX.split('{% each vars %}<i>{{it}}</i>{% endeach %}')
```

equivalent to the [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) function with the compiled pattern, finds all occurrences of text matching the regex in the argument string and returns a list of the parts divided by the matches - except that since the regex was in a capturing group (the parentheses in the regex string), the regex matches are also included in the list.

Comment: The exact code is on this website : http://alexmic.net/building-a-template-engine/

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment than an answer?

Comment: @gat: It answers the question, doesn't it?

Comment: @user3453437: Edit the proper code into the question.

Comment: Split returns all words whithout the first expression given which is used as a separator ... But on the example, it's return an array with all word are well-separated ... I don't understand why.

Comment: @user3453437: The `str.split` method is not the same as the `re.split` function or the `split` method of compiled regex objects. This code uses the regex method, not the string method.